# Change a value on a page depending on the selection from radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a rails app with a page to add up a total cost for people to review before they submit an order. I want the total to change depending on a set of options in a set of radio buttons.

How can I change a variable representing a total amount in a web page when a radio button selection is changed? I want this to happen without reloading the page.

Comment: You need to use ajax which will update your total amount

Comment: Mandeep, I don't think he needs ajax - just a way to calculate the total -- seems it could just be done using standard JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of it, you'll probably want to use standard Javascript / JQuery to add up the total on screen. This is opposed to the proposal of *ajax*, as you don't need to pull any extra data from the erver:

--

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqdyv6xr/)

```
#view
<input type="radio" name="option" value="3.99">Small (£3.99)<br>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="6.99" checked>Medium (£6.99)<br>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="9.99">Large (£9.99)<br>

<div class="total" >
    Total: &nbsp;
    <span id="total"></span>
</div>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", "input:radio[name=option]", change_value);
$(document).ready(change_value);

function change_value() {
    var value = $("input:radio[name=option]:checked").val();
    $("#total").html( "£" + value );
};
```

[image]